# How to implement a use-modal-hook with a alert/confirm/prompt pattern?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've started using [ReactModal](https://github.com/reactjs/react-modal) to display warning, prompts and such to the user.
This works well, but you have to add the component and `isOpen` state and callbacks everywhere you want to maybe display a modal window. Maybe I've misunderstood how to use it properly, but this pattern quickly becomes tedious.

I want to implement a sort of alert, confirm, prompt pattern where I can just say e.g:

```
const { myAlert, myConfirm } = useModal();

if(myConfirm('Show an alert?')) {
  myAlert('Alert!');
}
```

to show my modal in the desired way.

My problem lies with the functions. I want the app to wait for the user to click something in the modal before the following code is executed. Now my functions just instantly return after executing.

Here is my hook:

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { ModalContext } from '../App';
import Alert from '../components/Modals/Alert';
import Confirm from '../components/Modals/Confirm';

const useModal2 = () => {
  const { openModal, closeModal } = useContext(ModalContext);

  const alert = (message: string) => {
    openModal(
      <Alert title="Warning" message={message} closeAlert={closeModal} />
    );
  };
  const confirm = (question: string): boolean | undefined => {
    let answer;
    const closeConfirm = (ok: boolean) => {
      answer = ok;
      closeModal();
    };
    openModal(
      <Confirm
        title="Warning"
        question={question}
        closeConfirm={closeConfirm}
      />
    );
    return answer;
  };

  return { alert, confirm };
};

export default useModal2;
```

here is my Context and its values:

```
interface ModalContextType {
  openModal: (modal: ReactNode) => void;
  closeModal: () => void;
}
export const ModalContext = createContext<ModalContextType>({
  openModal: () => {},
  closeModal: () => {},
});
...
const App = () => {
...
  const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState<ReactNode>(null);
  const [isModalOpen, { openModal, closeModal }] = useModal();
  const open = (modal: ReactNode) => {
    setModalContent(modal);
    openModal();
  };
  const close = () => {
    setModalContent(null);
    closeModal();
  };
...
return (
  <ModalContext.Provider value={{ openModal: open, closeModal: close }}>
...
        <ReactModal
          className={styles.modalContent}
          overlayClassName={styles.modalOverlay}
          isOpen={isModalOpen}
          onRequestClose={close}
        >
          {modalContent}
        </ReactModal>
    ...
```

If I click the following button, the onClick function just outputs undefined before I click anything in the confirm dialog:

```
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const answer = confirm('Show an alert?');
          if (answer) {
            alert('The alert you requested!');
          }
          console.log(answer);
        }}
      >
        Confirm!
      </button>
```

how can I make it wait for my answer in the dialog before it checks the value in the `if` and runs the console.log? Any ideas?

Here is my code in codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-architecture-jtjyr

Comment: added sandbox link. If you open console then click confirm-button you see it prints "undefined" before you click any of the buttons in the modal. I want it to wait for me to click "Ok" or "Cancel"

Answer (score 0):

Just had to return a Promise from the functions supplied by my hook.

```
import { useContext } from 'react';
import { ModalContext } from '../App';
import Alert from '../components/Modals/Alert';
import Confirm from '../components/Modals/Confirm';

const useDialog = () => {
  const { openModal, closeModal } = useContext(ModalContext);

  const alertDialog = (message: string) => {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const closeAlert = () => {
        resolve(true);
        closeModal();
      };

      openModal(
        <Alert title="Warning" message={message} closeAlert={closeAlert} />
      );
    });
  };
  const confirmDialog = (message: string) => {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
      const closeConfirm = (value: boolean) => {
        resolve(value);
        closeModal();
      };

      openModal(
        <Confirm
          title="Warning"
          message={message}
          closeConfirm={closeConfirm}
        />
      );
    });
  };

  return { alertDialog, confirmDialog };
};

export default useModal2;
```

then you can use it like so:

```
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          const answer = await confirmDialog('Show an alert?');
          if (answer) {
            await alertDialog('The alert you requested!');
          }
          console.log('Done showing dialogs for now!');
        }}
      >
        Confirm!
      </button>
```

Would probably be cleaner to take care of the async/await somewhere else than where you open the dialogs. But thats a problem for another time.

Comment: I appreciate the time you took to help me, really. I might have worded it poorly, but my question was mainly aimed towards how to make the code-execution wait for the user to respond to the dialog. I made examples to demonstrate this issue ignoring things like readability and such. The examples doesnt not reflect the state of my real codebase. Thats why I got a bit annoyed when you seemed to comment more on irrelevant issue rather than the one i asked.